# C++ ampersand receiving object from function

Tags: c++, oop, object

I have the following simple code with a class including a normal constructor and a copy constructor

```
class largeObj
{
public:
    largeObj()
    {
        printf("\nNormal constructor\n");
    }

    largeObj(const largeObj& mv)
    {
        printf("\nCopy constructor\n");
    }

    ~largeObj()
    {
        printf("\nDestroying..\n");
    }

    void tryme()
    {
        printf("\nHi :)\n");
    }

};

largeObj iReturnLargeObjects()
{
    largeObj md;


    return md;
}


int main()
{

    largeObj mdd = iReturnLargeObjects();

    mdd.tryme();

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

> Normal constructor
>
> Copy constructor
>
> Destroying..
>
> hi :)

and I got why.

But if I substitute the following line

```
largeObj mdd = iReturnLargeObjects();
```

with

```
largeObj& mdd = iReturnLargeObjects();
```

The output is the same, why is that?

I mean: shouldn't there be another copy in the first case (without the &)? What's the difference between these two lines and why do they behave the same?

Comment: The second one shouldn't even compile. It's binding a temporary to a reference to non-const.

Comment: I did a bit of debugging and I found out that the normal constructor is called by the md object in the iReturnLargeObjects(), then the copy constructor is called upon return md; and then destructor is called on the md object just before returning from iReturnLargeObjects(). So presumably there's another largeObj created in memory. The question is: why the largeObj mdd = object does not create another copy variable? Is this because of the RVO? And so everyone here agrees that the second largeObj& mdd = object is totally illegal and compiled due to something weird

Comment: @ jrok, It should still compile. If you for instance create a reference on the stack, that reference isn't treated as a tempory because the compiler doesn't check to see where it came from, only that its a valid reference, so when it gets returned, its returned as a reference.  This Works ONLY BECAUSE it is the copy constructor.

Answer (score 4):

```
largeObj& mdd = iReturnLargeObjects();
```

You cannot bind a mutable lvalue reference to an rvalue. This is illegal C++ and only allowed by some specific compiler extensions. However, the semantics of the question are unchanged, even if this reference had been `const` and therefore the assignment legal.

The reason your outputs are no different is because of a compiler optimization called RVO. This optimization, which is explicitly allowed in the C++ Standard, allows the compiler to skip constructing objects which it determines are unnecessary, within certain restrictions- even if doing so changes the semantics of the program, which makes it a highly unusual optimization.

The bottom line is: Do not put side effects in your copy/move constructors and destructors, because the compiler can eliminate them even if your program's correctness depends upon them being called.

Comment: There's no RVO occuring here -- if there was, you wouldn't see the `Copy contructor` and `Destorying` messages before the `Hi`

Comment: Thank you, and what about in functions return types? I mean: largeObj& myFunction(); is returning references instead of simple largeObj better or thanks to the RVO I can forget about these things and simply return largeObj?

Answer (score 0):

What compiler did you use, I'm willing to bet this worked because whatever compiler you used didn't zero out unused stack variables after a return, you didn't get a seg fault because its still your stack.  basically md was left on the stack which you are technically still allowed to address.  The difference between the two is

> largeObj md;

is a variable receiving a variable in its entirety.

> largeObj& mdd = iReturnLargeObjects();

is a reference to a variable that due to a lazy compiler still exists.

Comment: Now that's weird, Visual studio is usually pretty good about doing all the things that aren't part of the standard but keeps coders from making silly mistakes.  Basically this works because the copy constructor returns a reference by definition. And the stack is not being cleared. Add this function before you call mdd.tryme() to see what I mean.  int messupstack(){char* a = "lllllllllllllllllllllll'";return 5;    
}

Comment: Wait, I'm retarded, that last section wont do anything because the tryme just prints out data not in the instance of the class.  You'd need class variables to see incorrect results.